# How to handle two route and direct to one Action in .NET-Core Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is my route rules  in Startup.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "UnsolvedTagspecial",
                    template: "user/undo/{t}",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "user", action = "undo" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "UnsolvedTag",
                    template: "user/{t}/undo",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "user", action = "undo" }
                    );
```

And here is my action in Controller:

```
//Controller:
public async Task<ActionResult> undo(string t)
{
    //   .....
}
```

- When I enter `http://localhost:17623/user/undo/111` in address line, I get the value of **t is null** in controller function;
- But when I enter `http://localhost:17623/user/111/undo` in address line, I get the value of **t = 111** in controller function;

It confuse me, who can tell me why ?

Comment: Most likely, you have a route *before* `"user/undo/{t}"` that is matching the pattern. Show the rest of your routes (including attribute routes).

Comment: I have a default route as @Usman said. And I solved the question as he said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because you have to set routes from most specific to most generic. i guess your routes will be like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "UnsolvedTagspecial",
                    template: "user/undo/{t}",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "user", action = "undo" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "UnsolvedTag",
                    template: "user/{t}/undo",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "user", action = "undo" }
                    );
```

so when you enter `http://localhost:17623/user/undo/111` it hits the first route which expects 111 to be `id` but when it goes to `action` the parameter expects `string t`. so you should place routes like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "UnsolvedTagspecial",
                    template: "user/undo/{t}",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "user", action = "undo" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "UnsolvedTag",
                    template: "user/{t}/undo",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "user", action = "undo" }
                    );
routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

from most **specific** to most **generic**

Comment: My MapRoute order is the same as you said ,cry.

Comment: And I have a another question following : my link is like that : `http://localhost:17623/user/undo/111`  my `controller = user '                      and  my  `action = undo` why is redirect to this rule                                                `routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`